# Early Binding with Generics

Tags: vb.net, generics, early-binding

I have a class which takes the method address and arguments, and executes it later when told to do so.

```
' need to turn option strict off due to Execute method executing late-bound code
Option Strict Off

Public Class WorkItem
    Private Action As Object
    Private Args() As Object

    Public Overloads Sub [Set](action As Action)
        SetArgs(action)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub [Set](Of T)(action As Action(Of T), arg As T)
        SetArgs(action, arg)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub [Set](Of T1, T2)(action As Action(Of T1, T2), arg1 As T1, arg2 As T2)
        SetArgs(action, arg1, arg2)
    End Sub

    '*** more overloads of [Set] method go here... 

    Private Sub SetArgs(ByVal action As Object, ParamArray args() As Object)
        Me.Action = action
        Me.Args = args
    End Sub

    Public Sub Execute()
        '-- early binding doesn't work
        'DirectCast(Me.Action, Action(Of T)).Invoke(Args(0))  

        '-- this works, but forces me to to keep option strict off
        Select Case Args.Length
            Case 0 : Me.Action.Invoke()
            Case 1 : Me.Action.Invoke(Args(0))
            Case 2 : Me.Action.Invoke(Args(0), Args(1))
            Case 3 : Me.Action.Invoke(Args(0), Args(1), Args(2))
            Case 4 : Me.Action.Invoke(Args(0), Args(1), Args(2), Args(3))
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is some tester code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim TheTask As WorkItem

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TheTask = New WorkItem
        TheTask.Set(AddressOf DummyProc, TextBox1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TheTask.Execute()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DummyProc(arg As TextBox)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Debug.Print("work completed")
    End Sub
End Class
```

The `WorkItem` class obviously doesn't work with `OPTION STRICT ON`, due to the late-bound call in `Execute` method.

Is there any way I can convert the late-bound call to early binding?

Comment: why not use delegates? They are made for this kind of activities, no?

Comment: From this code snippet, there's no need for `WorkItem` to know about `Args` - have `WorkItem` just hold an `Action`, and pass it a delegate which invokes the method *with the specific argument*. Then `WorkItem.Execute` is just `Me.Action.Invoke()`.

Comment: @A.S.H, I'm ok with delegates as long as the code is generic and independent of the caller. How do I go about it?

Comment: @AakashM, The `Me.Action.Invoke()` needs one argument for where Action is of type `Action(Of T)`. I may be missing the point completely though. Can you show me how to modify my code for this?

Comment: My `WorkItem.Action` is declared as `Object` because I don't know in advance how many arguments the method will have. So no idea whether it would be `Action` or `Action(Of T)` or `Action(Of T1, T2)` etc. What I showed above is just the minimal code to reproduce the problem. My actual class has multiple overloads of the `Set` method. They accept `Action`, `Action(Of T)`... etc.

Comment: Updated the `WorkItem` code in my question so that it gives a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: I think my question is a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since my code is already working and I'm just trying to improve it. But I don't know how to move this question there. Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: If you want your question to be moved, you can flag it for moderator attention and request a migration. I'd say this question looks good to go and have done that.

Comment: Okay, for the record... my flag for migration was declined. I'll see if I can pull some strings to get this to Code Review by migration. If all else fails, you can manually cross-post the question

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx). You can declare a delegate that represents a non-generic subroutine, and invoke a representation of that delegate on an object that passed `arg` as a constructor parameter. I don't know if your solution still needs a generic work item by implementing it like this, but my example still keeps that same setup:

```
Delegate Sub WorkItem()

Dim TheTask As WorkItem

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TheTask = AddressOf (New DummyProc(Of TextBox)(TextBox1)).Execute
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TheTask.Invoke()
End Sub

Private Class DummyProc(Of T)

    Private ReadOnly _arg As T

    Public Sub New(ByVal arg As T)
        _arg = arg
    End Sub

    Public Sub Execute()
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("My Arg: {0}", _arg))
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        MessageBox.Show("work completed")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have control over which method is to be executed. It is passed at runtime from user code to the `WorkItem` class. So this method doesn't to solve my problem.