# C# delay function calls by condition

Tags: c#, function, delay

In C#, I have a set of function candidates that will run in the future:   void func1(int); void func2(float); void func3(string);...and many more.

some code will decide which func123... will run (or none will run), and decide the parameter value}

if (ConditionMetToRun){run that function with parameter;}

How can I do this??

---

ok here's an example

> void WearSunStuff(whichSunscreen, whichSunglasses);
>
> void OpenUmbrella(whichUmbrella);
>
> void WearCoat(whichCoat);

Then I look out the windows and see it's raining. I'd better open my umbrella.
But I'm at home, I don't need to open my favorite black umbrella YET.

```
If(FriendingIsCallingMeToGoOutside)
{

    OpenUmbrella(blackUmbrella);
    GoOutSideToMeetMyFriend();
}
```

or.....
Then I look out the windows and see it's really co. I'd better wear my coat.
But I'm at home, I don't need to open my favorite yellow coat YET.

```
If(FriendingIsCallingMeToGoOutside)
{
WearCoat(yelloCoat);
GoOutSideToMeetMyFriend();
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You want a background thread that polls a list of functions that are queued?

Comment: Seriously nobody knows what you are asking... Do you want them as thread, just overloaded functions or something completely different. Pls edit your answer to make it more clear. And maybe some sample code/usage and what you already have tried.

Comment: I don't need a queue, just one function will be called eventually.

Comment: You say eventually, meaning you want to know how to run these on a schedule? Or you want to know how to invoke functions on your FutureCandidates object dynamically?

Comment: The question here is probably what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906332/early-binding-with-generics It is working code; I posted it for a different reason. You can just rewrite it in c# or use any free online convertor to convert it to c#.

Comment: how to invoke functions on your FutureCandidates functions dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FutureCandidates futureCandidates = new FutureCandidates();

System.Reflection.MethodInfo func = futureCandidates.GetType().GetMethod("OpenUmbrella"); //OR WearCoat
if(FriendingIsCallingMeToGoOutside)
{
    func.Invoke(futureCandidates, new object[] { blackUmbrella });
    GoOutSideToMeetMyFriend();
}
```

Comment: @johnsquare-rerises-li - Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: The problem is that I must determine the function call and parameter before FriendingIsCallingMeToGoOutside.

Comment: Then just move `var func` outside the if

Comment: perhaps I didn't fully understand?  What does .GetType().GetMethod("OpenUmbrella") do? can you write c#?

Comment: The solution mentioned above is C#, are you sure you should be asking questions and not maybe learn a bit more about the language first. If you are using an older version of .Net replace the var with the return type of the right hand side of the declaration.